# preg_replace with regex searching for question marks inside h[1-6]-Tags

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

Im using a Google Font ([Amatic SC](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Amatic+SC)) that shows in his bold version a ®-symbol instead of an question mark.

To fix this problem I wanted to use **preg_replace**, **searching for any kind of question marks** (?,¿) inside my $content **within h1-h6 Tags** (Im only using this font in the headlines) and wrapping them inside an extra span element to assign them a different class so that I can use the normal version istead of the bold version of the font.

Since im not that familiar with Regular Expressions I had quite some difficulties to get this right. I dont know how to search just for the Question Marks and wrap just them inside an extra span.

Current Wordpress Code inside the function.php:

```
function replace_content($content){
    $regex = '#(<h([1-6])[^>]*>)\s?(.*)?\s?(<\/h\2>)#';
    $content = preg_replace($regex,'\1<span class="normal">\3</span>\4',$content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

The Function should replace something like this markup:

```
<h1>¿This is a questions?</h1>
```

with thisone:

```
<h1><span class="normal">¿</span>This is a questions<span class="normal">?</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a regex here (which contrary to common memes is totally apt for well-known output) you should preferrably use two. This allows to separate context from the actual target:

```
$regex = '#(<h([1-6])[^>]*>)([^<>]+)(<\/h\2>)#';
$content = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($match) {
    return
        "$match[1]"
      . preg_replace("/[¿?]/u", "<span class='normal'>$0</span>", $match[3])
      . "$match[4]";
}, $content);
```

Where the [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) passes the whole headline to the substitution function. And `[¿?]` matches the characters you're looking for. (Anonymous functions need PHP 5.3)

Another option would be to just utilize CSS for font-substitution.
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#composite-fonts

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Amatic SC";
  src: url(fonts/amatic.ttf);
  unicode-range: U+00-3E, U+40-7F;
}
```

That will make symbols outside of your fonts character range fall back on a default font anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cascading callback function here if you are content with using a regular expression.

```
$text = <<<DATA
<h1>¿This is a questions?</h1>
<h2>¿This is a questions?</h2>
<h3>¿This is a questions?</h3>
DATA;

$text = preg_replace_callback('~<h([1-6])>[^<]++</h\1>~', 
      function($m) {
         return preg_replace('~[¿?]~u', '<span class="normal">$0</span>', $m[0]);
      }, $text);
```

Output

```
<h1><span class="normal">¿</span>This is a questions<span class="normal">?</span></h1>
<h2><span class="normal">¿</span>This is a questions<span class="normal">?</span></h2>
<h3><span class="normal">¿</span>This is a questions<span class="normal">?</span></h3>
```